# notify users that they need to stop using IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

Are there any jQuery plugins or templates that people use to get poeple to stop using IE6 on their websites? 

I recently saw a plugin that was very obtrusive and offensive that "warned" users of evil of IE6. I am looking for something one can show their customers.

Comment: Not that I do not agree with reducing IE6 or IE's use on the web, but there are some companies (very few) that have not upgraded to IE7 or better alternatives.

Comment: I agree. Some people are stuck with IE6. I am building a small "personal" webpage, so i can be more selective with my audience.

Comment: At this point, I have very little sympathy with such companies. IE7 was released 2.5 years ago. It's time for them to get their thumbs out of their collective asses and fix their intranet apps.

Comment: if those companies make up 97% of your target audience then you would have to cater to their wishes no? This is the problem with being a web developer these days, the rest of the world does not care about what YOU think

Comment: I have seen sites that work on 6 but still do not work on 7.  Imagine if you have to use two sites, one of which doesn't support 7, and the other which doesn't support 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a div that only IE6 users see.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<div>
  Using IE 6 will curve your spine, please upgrade your version
  of Internet Explorer or download Firefox, Opera, Safari or Chrome.
</div>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: 'lt'?  Surely that should be 'lte'.

Comment: yeah I goofed, either the hard test above, or the <!--[if IE lte 6]> version would be more complete.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that many web users are 'held up' using IE6 because of their big corporation's IT department.

They already know about the need to upgrade and your message aggravates them further. Why make them more miserable? At least give a gentle message explaining why you can't support IE6.

Comment: They're typically not held up by their IT departments, they're held up by the technical requirements that target a specific browser like IE.

Comment: Actually, many bigger corporate IT departments do hold up the process.  +1

Answer (score 4):

You can code it yourself with CSS.

Either use conditional comments in HTML to use a specific stylesheet for IE6

```
<!--[if IE6]>  whatever  <![endif]-->
```

or put the message in a layer (div) and make it visible only for IE6:

```
display: none !important;
*display: block;
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally find any sort of messages telling me to use a particular browser both arrogant and a sign of laziness on the part of the developer/designer.

My reasoning is that if *I* am somehow able to make compatible cross-browser designs, why can't others?  It becomes even more trivial when you consider "browser normalizers" that exists as javascript libraries or JQuery plugins which essentially nullify the minor differences.

Here is a [good example](http://devsnippets.com/article/15-jquery-plugins-to-fix-and-beautify-browser-issues.html) of what I mean.

Comment: Again, i agree, i could NEVER tell a user to use a certain browser if they were a client at my JOB. On the other hand, when i make websites for free and fun, i can absolutely tell anyone anything. i have decided to not support IE6 because supporting it is boring.

Comment: However, you can support IE6 with a basic, non-fully functional but working version and tell users that it they would get much better experience with a better browser.

Many IE6 users don't know that there are better options (not being arrogant, just factical)

Comment: Actually, we frequently tell users what browser they should be using and they understand why. We're not in the habit wasting our time testing with browsers that should have been replaced long ago. Strangely enough, we don't support running our software on Windows 3.1 either :-)

Comment: There are a fixed set of rules to follow for IE compatibility. Most of those rules are things like "explicitly specify heading sizes".  Its not any extra effort to make IE look and act the same. And its accepted that IE6 may have a degraded experience, but you should degrade gracefully.

Comment: IE6 can cause all kinds of nightmares for developers, not just predictable display differences. I've spent tons of time on real-time visualizations where I had to write lots of extra code for IE6.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  Puts a polite notification bar at the top of the page.
(Courtesy [think2loud](http://think2loud.com/build-an-unsupported-browser-warning-with-jquery/), see this link for full source, sample, css, etc.).

```
function badBrowser(){
    if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6){ return true;}

    return false;
}

function getBadBrowser(c_name)
{
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
    {
    c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start!=-1)
        { 
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
        if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        } 
    }
    return "";
}   

function setBadBrowser(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}

if(badBrowser() && getBadBrowser('browserWarning') != 'seen' ){
    $(function(){
        $("<div id='browserWarning'>You are using an unsupported browser. Please switch to <a href='http://getfirefox.com'>FireFox</a>, <a href='http://www.opera.com/download/'>Opera</a>, <a href='http://www.apple.com/safari/'>Safari</a> or <a href='http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/ie/getitnow.mspx'>Internet Explorer 7</a>. Thanks!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href='#' id='warningClose'>close</a>] </div> ")
            .css({
                backgroundColor: '#fcfdde',
                'width': '100%',
                'border-top': 'solid 1px #000',
                'border-bottom': 'solid 1px #000',
                'text-align': 'center',
                padding:'5px 0px 5px 0px'
            })
            .prependTo("body");

        $('#warningClose').click(function(){
            setBadBrowser('browserWarning','seen');
            $('#browserWarning').slideUp('slow');
            return false;
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: code like that really bugs me. cut the return true/false and just
return ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6);

Comment: code like this freaks me out. is this good code when the author does not know how booleans work? I tend to have less trust in the overall quality of code when i see things like this